# Testing in Laravel, setUp & tearDown doesn't rollBack my database transaction?

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4

I'm having this weired behaviour in Laravel testing. Let me show you my tests.

```
<?php 
class MatchesControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        DB::beginTransaction();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        DB::rollBack();

    }

     public function testForFun()
    {
             $title = 'Yay Great Post';
        // "Create" post
        Post::create(compact('title'));
             $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', 'posts');

        $this->assertEquals(
            1,
            count($crawler->filter("body:contains('{$title}')")),
            "Expected to see the text '{$title}' within a body element."
        );
    }
}
```

Now ideally, the test should create a row and delete as soon as the test ends but its not happening, is there something else I should have done. I know the rollback is called when some unexpected exception has occured but I'm deliberately calling it at the end, won't this should work as we think it should?

Comment: is `rollBack()` method invoked? Doesn't `Post::create()` invoke its own `commit()`?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue.  From what I can tell `::create()` does not utilize a transaction.  Even if it did, Laravel supports nested transactions.

Comment: oh, so thats the reason, why it doesn't work like we expected!

Comment: try to call parent::tearDown(); on tearDown method, before you do the rollback

Comment: @KbirMhrjn Post::create() does save the model into the database as well. the create() function is in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder and calls the `$instance->save();` method.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Laravel 5, you can add the DatabaseMigrations trait:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class MatchesControllerTest extends TestCase {
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function testForFun() { 
       // your test.. 
    }
}
```

That trait creates and removes the database tables you've defined in your [migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations) just for your test. More on that trait in the [Laravel testing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test)